# regex for triple quote

Tags: python, regex

What regex will find the triple quote comments (possibly multi-line) in a Python source code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python is not a regular language and cannot reliably be parsed using regex.

If you want a proper Python parser, look at the [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module. You may be looking for `get_docstring`.

Comment: +1: Question has no valid solution using regexes, only half-working hacks.

Comment: I believe regular expressions are powerful enough to do this right. But constructing proper regexp for such task is hard, so using built-in python parser is more reliable solution.

Comment: Do you have a link for that? 'Cannot be reliably parsed using regex'. Which languages can?

Comment: Barely-readable summary of theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language. Most programming languages aren't, but then modern regex has extensions that take it well beyond traditional regular language matching. Python's syntax, however, is still too complex to be amenable to regex.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612654/is-regex-in-modern-programming-languages-really-context-sensitive-grammar

Answer (score 5):

```
re.findall('(?:\n[\t ]*)\"{3}(.*?)\"{3}', s, re.M | re.S)
```

captures only text within triple quotes that are at the begging of a line and could be preceded by spaces, tabs or nothing, as python docstrings should be.

Comment: and what about this: `a = '""" not a real triple quote """'`

Comment: why is it not a real triple quote? is there something lost in formatting?

Comment: I suppose quite similar regex could be used to get single quotes as well (it's quite easy to extend given example), I just see no point in stuffing single regex to the point of unintelligibility.

Comment: because it's inside a simple quote... so it's part of a string literal.

Comment: is that a raw string, bobince?

Comment: Worked for me, when a lot of other stuff failed on complicated docstrings with multiple quotes on the interior. Good job. If you want a quick easy way to remove docstrings from python source, just use this. +1

Answer (score 4):

I find this to be working perfectly for me (used it with TextMate):

```
"{3}([\s\S]*?"{3})
```

I wanted to remove all comments from a library and this took care of the triple-quote comments (single or multi-line, regardless of where they started on the line).

For hash comments (much easier), this works:

```
#.*$
```

I used these with TextMate, which uses the Oniguruma regular expression library by K. Kosako (http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions)

Comment: Note that weak repetition (`*?`) is reliable for matching just a triqle-quoted string but gets risky if you build a bigger pattern from it.  E.g. `\("""[\s\S]*?"""\)` does NOT mean one triple quoted string in parentheses — it will also match `("""1st string""" whatever... """2nd string""")`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this one from Tim Peters (I think) :

```
pat = """
    qqq
    [^\\q]*
    (
    (   \\\\[\000-\377]
        |   q
        (   \\\\[\000-\377]
        |   [^\\q]
        |   q
        (   \\\\[\000-\377]
            |   [^\\q]
        )
        )
    )
    [^\\q]*
    )*
    qqq
"""  
pat = ''.join(pat.split(), '')  
tripleQuotePat = pat.replace("q", "'") + "|" + pat.replace('q', '"')
```

But, as stated by bobince, regex alone doesn't seem to be the right tool for parsing Python code.
So I went with **tokenize** from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this will fair when scanning Python code, but this seems to match Python strings in isolation.

```
^(\"([^\"\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"|'([^'\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*'|\"\"\"((?!\"\"\")[^\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"\"\")$
```

The escaping is not standard Python; this is something that I cut-n-pasted from a project.  See it in action at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aGoSsg/3).