# Pathological regex that blows up (time & memory)?

Tags: php, python, regex, perl

What's a pathological regex that blows up many parsers (both in time & memory)?
and which parsers? Bonus points the more basic and standard the regex is, and the more likely that a non-malicious user might innocently come up with it.
Feel free to post actual time and memory data, and parser version.

(I seem to remember that excessive lookbehind assertions or (EDIT:)backtracking in PERL are said to do this, or at least used to be. Anything else?)

Comment: Your thinking of backtracking, almost any NFA based regex engine can be tricked into quasi-infinite backtracking if you can control both the subject and pattern. DFA based engines don't need to do backtracking, so they don't suffer that pitfall. The answer to the next questions is "Because a DFA typically can't support the features an NFA can."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from the first example in the article [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast
(but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html):

```
perl -e '$n=29; ("a" x $n) =~ (("a?" x $n).("a" x $n))'
```

Which takes 40+ seconds on my system.  Then do `$n++` for exponentially increasing fun...

Comment: It's odd that every regex engine doesn't optimize this.  Reducing `a?a?` to `a{,2}` is so basic that it's taught in classes.

Comment: Synthetic example but useful essay with comparisons across languages.

Answer (score 3):

From Russ Cox's excellent [article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html): `$ perl -e '("a" x 100000) =~ /^(ab?)*$/;'`. This apparently causes a segfault. There are more in the article.

Comment: Python and GNU grep have no trouble with this.  `re.match(r'^(ab?)*$', 'a'*10000000)`

Comment: This did not cause a problem with my perl 5.10.1 install, and seems to run fine on codepad which is 5.8 http://codepad.org/hFlqUWk8

Comment: @Eric Strom: I think the author was testing against perl 5.8.7.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: I get a `MemoryError` when I try that on my machine (Python 2.6.5).

Comment: @Glenn Maynard, GNU grep is DFA based, it isn't going to fail on this set up because this example targets a common weakness of NFA based engines.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: thanks, it would help if you list which tools are NFA-based and which DFA-based.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu  it's not about NFA or DFA, it's whether the engine uses backtracking or not.  NFA based engines can use an efficient, non-backtracking approach which doesn't fall prey to pathological regexes.

Comment: @ErikHaliewicz your putting words in my mouth. I didn't say all NFA base engines failed on these expressions, only that it was common. Your correct that the problem is backtracking, but I was specifically answering why GNU grep didn't fail. GNU grep is uses a DFA, DFA's don't as a rule backtrack because there is never an alternate state to backtrack to.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this regex to match strings inside PHP or JavaScript source code in PHP:

```
~'(\\.|[^'])*'|"(\\.|[^"])*"~s
```

And it almost always fail on a very long string (about 50000 chars long will do).

Comment: This uses ~ delimiter because it contains both types of quotes; tried to to convert it to a Python regex to test it but the escaping drives me nuts. Can anyone convert it?

Comment: I mostly converted it using [this approach due to Tim Peters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472047/regex-for-triple-quote) except for the s modifier (dot matches every character?)... I suspect that makes it worse.

Comment: [This poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004023/translate-the-intent-of-this-php-regex-for-multiline-strings-into-python-perl/7006231#7006231) improved the efficiency of your regex, check it out!