# Translate the intent of this PHP regex for multiline strings, into Python/PERL

Tags: php, python, regex, multiline

Below is a PHP regex intended to match (multiline) strings inside PHP or JavaScript source code (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307143/pathological-regex-that-blows-up-time-memory/5307226#5307226)), but I suspect it's got issues.
What is the literal Python (or else PERL) equivalent of this?

```
~'(\\.|[^'])*'|"(\\.|[^"])*"~s
```

- the [s modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) means dot matches all characters, including newline; in Python that's `re.compile(..., re.DOTALL)`
- I totally don't get the intent of the leading `\\.` ? Does that reduce to `.` ? Are double-backslashes need to escape it twice in PHP?
- allowing in **every** position a match of either `\\.` or `[^']` (any non-quote character) seems total overkill to me, maybe explains why this person's regex blows up. Does `[^']` group not already match everything that `.` with s modifier does, surely it should match newlines?
- for constructing two versions of the regex with single, and double, quotes in Python, can use [this two-step approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472047/regex-for-triple-quote)
- NB a simpler version of this regex can also be found in this [list of PHP regex examples, under Programming: String](http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html).

Comment: I just re-read the question and now I'm confused.  In that other thread you were looking for regexes that can cause a system to freeze or crash, and this regex was one of the answers.  What are you after this time?  Do you want to *improve* the regex, or do you just want to find out if it bogs down in Python like it does in PHP?

Comment: @Alan, this question means exactly what it says: explain the intent of THIS guy's PHP regex, i.e. exactly what multiline strings this regex matches. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is mostly okay, except it doesn't handle escaped quotes (i.e., `\"` and `\'`).  That's easy enough to fix:

```
'(?:\\.|[^'\\]+)*'|"(?:\\.|[^"\\]+)*"
```

That's a "generic" regex; in Python you would usually write it in the form of a raw string:

```
r"""'(?:\\.|[^'\\]+)*'|"(?:\\.|[^"\\]+)*""""
```

In PHP you have to escape the backslashes to get them past PHP's string processing:

```
'~\'(?:\\\\.|[^\'\\\\]+)*\'|"(?:\\\\.|[^"\\\\]+)*"~s'
```

Most of the currently-popular languages have either a string type that requires less escaping, support for regex literals, or both.  Here's how your regex would look as a C# verbatim string:

```
@"'(?:\\.|[^'\\]+)*'|""(?:\\.|[^""\\]+)*"""
```

But, formatting considerations aside, the regex itself should work in any Perl-derived flavor (and many other flavors as well).

---

p.s.: Notice how I added the `+` quantifier to your character classes.  Your intuition about matching one character at a time is correct; adding the `+` makes a *huge* difference in performance.  But don't let that fool you; when you're dealing with regexes, intuition seems to wrong more often than not. :/

Comment: The original regex _does_ handle escaped quotes, the `\\.` will match before the `[^']` so it works fine. Your point about improving performance by adding `+` is valid, but only then is it also necessary exclude the backslash in the character classes.

Comment: @Long Ears: it does okay on well-formed string literals, but it also matches things it shouldn't, like `"\"`.  At first, the `\\.` alternative matches the `\"`, but that leaves nothing for the final `"` to match.  So it backs off and allows the `[^.]` alternative to match the backslash instead, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Well if you're taking malformed source code into account then you should be using a full lexer not a simple regex. Having no matches doesn't imply correctness either way ;)

Comment: @Long: I don't think the OP is really using it for that purpose anyway, but I'm not sure what the purpose *is*.

Answer (score 2):

The `\\.` is meant to match a literal backslash in the pattern, and swallow the following character. Note that since patterns in PHP (and Python) are contained in strings, it would actually need to be `\\\\.` in the string, so that it ends up as `\\.` in the regex.

It's important to match the backslash and swallow the following character because it could be used to escape a quote which would otherwise end the match prematurely.

This pattern looks like it should work fine, and I can't think of a more succinct way to express it.

It should also work fine in Python (as you say, with re.DOTALL). In Python you could use the raw string notation to save the extra escaping of the backslash although you'd still need to escape the single quote. This should be equivalent:

`re.search(r'\'(\\.|[^\'])*\'|"(\\.|[^"])*"', str, re.DOTALL)`