# What do I need to keep in mind when accepting and running regexes from users?

Tags: regex, security, web, user-input

I would like to take regexes from users and then run them against other user-submitted input and display the output. What do I need to keep in mind, if anything, to protect against attacks?

Comment: Some regular expression implementations allow running arbitrary code. Otherwise, the only concern *I* can think of is a DoS caused by very degenerate expressions. In any case, this question is very "hypothetical" now. Consider grounding it with a current implementation of such a situation - including applicable language/runtime.

Comment: Expanding on @user2864740's comment, keep in mind that some patterns may be perfectly valid but require *lots* of resources to evaluate. Users could abuse this to bring your server to a crawl with only a few requests. This question is probably better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

A carefully crafted regex and match string might take large amounts of CPU time to execute; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307143/pathological-regex-that-blows-up-time-memory). So you want to, at the very least, perform the matching in a separate thread and kill the thread after 2-3 seconds. If you want to limit both time and memory usage, you'll need to fork off an entirely new process and use something like [this](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40) to monitor its CPU and memory usage.

Comment: Well said. e.g. apply a regex like: `^((a*a*a*)*)*$` to the string `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"` and you would hang the system without these timeout safeguards. +1

Answer (score 1):

atomic groups (non capturing groups) are very useful to avoid any denial of service attacks by gobbling up servers memory, what is called catastrophic backtracking, and also performance wise atomic groups are very useful.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider Base64 encoding the regex if it is going to be written to a database to eliminate the special characters, and make sure you're using parameterized queries to help quell SQL injection attacks.

Once the RegEx is run against the other user input, run it through some code to escape any unexpected HTML output prior to it being displayed in the browser.

Comment: If the regular expression is saved in the database then *placeholders* should be used. There is *no* reason to even suggest Base64 here - should user comments also be Base64 encoded if they are saved in the database?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure there are no security flaws in the RegEx implementation you choose to use.

That's all you need to worry about. As long as there are no security flaws, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: Even if it allows for DoS?