# Javascript flavor regex for identifying valid Python strings enclosed within triple quotes

Tags: javascript, python, regex, google-code-prettify

I'm trying to write a [Prettify-style syntax highlighter](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/388/26) for [Qiskit Terra](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/index.html) (which closely follows the Python syntax). Apparently, Prettify uses Javascript flavor regex. For instance, `/^\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)/, null, '"'` is the regex corresponding to valid strings in [Q#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_Sharp). Basically I'm trying to put together the equivalent regex expression for Python.

Now, I know that Python supports strings within triple quotes i.e. `'''<string>'''` and `"""<string>"""` are valid strings (this format is especially used for [docstrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring)). To deal with this case I wrote the corresponding **capturing group** as:

```
(^\'{3}(?:[^\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'{3}$))
```

Here is the [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/k4adk2/5).

This [works okay](https://regex101.com/r/k4adk2/6) except in some cases like:

```
''' 'This "is" my' && "first 'regex' sentence." ''' &&
''' 'This "is" the second.' '''
```

Clearly here it should have considered `''' 'This "is" my' && "first 'regex' sentence." '''` as one string and `''' 'This "is" the second.' '''` as another. But no, the regex I wrote groups together the whole thing as one string (check the [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/k4adk2/5)). That is, it doesn't conclude the string even when it encounters a `'''` (corresponding to the `'''` at the beginning).

How should I modify the regex `(^\'{3}(?:[^\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'{3}$))` to take into account this case? I'm aware of this: [How to match “anything up until this sequence of characters” in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres) but it doesn't quite answer my question, at least not directly.

Comment: Check out a sublime module for syntax highlighting. And go through the regex snippets. https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython in grammars might help some.

Comment: @Raymond Thanks, checking. I just noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472047/regex-for-triple-quote/1472390#1472390) which makes me wonder whether it's possible using Regex at all. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know what else you want to use this for but the following regex does what you want with the example given with the MULTILINE flag on.

```
My_search = re.findall("(?:^\'{3})(.*)(?:\'{3})", My_string, re.MULTILINE)

print(My_search[0])
print(My_search[1])
```

Output is,

```
'This "is" my' && "first 'regex' sentence." 
'This "is" the second.'
```

You can also see it working here https://regex101.com/r/k4adk2/11

Comment: It solves the examples given in the OP but it does not handle the general case of tripple quote strings, as they can contain escaped quotes, e.g. in`r""""\""""` `\"` should be caught.