# Is there a parsing algorithm for languages generated by context-sensitive grammars?

Tags: parsing, nlp, bnf, automata-theory, context-sensitive-grammar

### Details

I am already familiar with Chart Parsing using [Earley Parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser). I am however, unsure about whether there even is a meta-syntax like [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) (BNF) that can represent a [Context-Sensitive Grammar (CSG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar). Since parsing using a [Linear Bounded Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton) is non-deterministic, I understand that it may be very inefficient.

### Goal

My goal is to create a Probabilistic Context-Sensitive Grammar generator from a corpus (in the same fashion as a [PCFG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_context-free_grammar)). Ambiguous grammars will handled by generating parse forests and possibly utilizing something like [SPPF](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066108001497) if there is an equivalent of Earley Parsers for CSGs.

### What I've Tried

I was recommended [ABNF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5234/), but it's not obvious if it supports CSGs. Another recommendation was to use Dependency Parsing instead of Constituency Parsing. But that is an entirely different approach from what I want to solve.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482667/how-to-parse-context-sensitive-grammar) seems to indicate that simply simulating an LBA with backtracking is enough. However, again that seems incredibly inefficient.